Coarse-graining a bounded-incidence hypergraph
Let $G$ be a connected hypergraph with vertex-set $V$ and hyperedge-set $E \subseteq 2^V\smallsetminus \{\emptyset\}$. Assume that every vertex is part of at most $\Delta$ hyperedges and every hyperedge has at most $\Delta$ vertices. I call such $G$ a bounded-incidence hypergraph.
Let $n\ge1$ be an integer and $c>0$ be a real constant. I define a good cover of $G$ as a collection $\{G_1,G_2,\ldots\}$ of sub-hypergraphs of $G$ such that

each $G_i$ is a connected, induced sub-hypergraph of $G$,
there is an integer $m\ge1$ such that every hyperedge of $G$ is contained in at least one and at most $m$ distinct $G_i$'s.
there is an integer $N\ge n$ such that $n\le |V(G_i)|\le N$ for each $i$, and
for each $i$, we have
$$
\sum_{j\,:\, G_i \cap G_j \ne \emptyset} e^{-c |V(G_i \cap G_j)|} \le \frac12.
$$

Given an individual hypergraph $G$, it is easy to construct good covers, but I want to do this uniformly for all bounded-incidence hypergraphs. More precisely,
Question: are there integers $m$ and $N$ which depend only on $\Delta$, $n$, and $c$ such that every hypergraph of bounded-incidence $\Delta$ has a good cover with these parameters for sufficiently large $n$?
Edit: As per @caduk's comment, here is a more precise version of the question. Is the following statement true?

$\forall \Delta,c, \exists n_0, \forall n>n_0, \exists m,N, \forall G$ with $|V(G)| \ge n$ and maximum incidence $\Delta$, there is a good cover of $G$ with these parameters.


One can interpret $G_i$'s as "coarse-grained" hyperedges that form a "coarse-grained" hypergraph on the original vertex-set $V$. Intuitively, the coarse-grained hyperedges contain at least $n$ vertices, but not too many due to condition 3. More importantly, the size of overlap between two coarse-grained hyperedges cannot be too small due to condition 4. At the same time, the number of such overlaps (i.e., the number of coarse-grained hyperedges containing a given vertex) cannot be too large due to condition 2.
While these may seem impossible to be satisfied simultaneously, it is easy to construct a good cover uniformly for all graphs (i.e., each hyperedge is an edge). The idea is to construct a good cover uniformly for all trees and then use the fact that every graph has a spanning tree. I know an algorithmic way to construct a good cover of any tree such that $m \sim \Delta^3 n$ and $N \sim \Delta^3 n^2$. (See this answer to a related question I posted on mathoverflow a while ago.) However, for hypergraphs, there is no spanning tree in general, so this algorithm does not extend easily.
I would appreciate any help in solving this problem, or pointing me to any relevant literature.

Update:
I realized that the fourth condition can be satisfied if the following conditions are met:

for each $i,j$, either $G_i \cap G_j = \emptyset$ or $|V(G_i\cap G_j)| \ge n$, and
$N$ and $m$ grow polynomially in $n$.

Let me explain why these are sufficient. First, for each $i$, let us count the number of $j$ such that $G_i \cap G_j \ne \emptyset$. Since each $G_i$ has at most $N$ vertices, each vertex is part of at most $\Delta$ hyperedges, and each hyperedge is contained in at most $m$ $G_j$'s, there are at most $N \times \Delta \times m$ $G_j$'s that intersect $G_i$ nontrivially. Therefore, the fourth condition is satisfied because
$$
\sum_{j\,:\,G_i \cap G_j \ne \emptyset} e^{-c|V(G_i\cap G_j)|} \le \Delta N m e^{-cn},
$$
which can be made smaller than $1/2$ for sufficiently large $n$.
Both these conditions are indeed satisfied in the case of graphs. So the question is if this is the case for hypergraphs too. I would appreciate any thoughts or comments.

Update 2:
I wanted to explain quickly how to prove that a good cover exists for all graphs. I first want to construct a partition and then construct a good cover using it. Let $P$ be the set of "covered" vertices, which is initially empty. In the induced subgraph on $V(G)\setminus P$, pick a largest possible connected induced subgraph of size at most $n+1$. If the size of this subgraph is at least $n$, call it a "good" part, else call it "bad" part. Add the vertices in this part to $P$ and repeat until $P=V(G)$. The nice thing about this construction is that the "bad" parts are never adjacent to each other (if they were adjacent, we could have built a larger connected part by combining them). Now, define the $G_i$'s for the good cover as follows: for each part, take the union of that part and all the "good" parts adjacent to it. It is easy to see that these $G_i$'s satisfy conditions 1, 2, and 3. For condition 4, I use the formulation given in the update above. Indeed, if $G_i$ and $G_j$ intersect, they must do so on a "good" part because no two "bad" parts are adjacent. Therefore, any nontrivial intersection contains at least $n$ vertices. QED.
The key issue with extending this approach to hypergraphs is that the "bad" parts could be adjacent. So the argument for "intersection of $\ge n$" doesn't go through. I don't know how to avoid this. The existing answer below has a very similar problem. It satisfies the first three conditions, but not the "intersection of $\ge n$" condition.

I think we need at least that $|V(G)|\geq n$? Also, from the question, my understanding is that $n$ and $c$ are fixed and we can choose $m$ and $N$, but in the update, we choose $n$ depending on $c$ (Ok, we can take $n$ sufficiently large, but that does not necessarily mean sufficiently large compared to $c$). Can we get a full characterization of the question with all quantifiers in the correct order, for example, is it correct to rephrase your question as: $\forall c,\exists n_c,\forall n\geq n_c,\exists m,N,\forall G\text{ with } |V(G)|\geq n$, there is a good cover?

@caduk. You are right about everything. I’ll update the question when I find time later today to incorporate your comment.

Posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/481817/coarse-graining-a-hypergraph

I think the following should work:
We will create a partition of the vertices in connected induced components of size $n+\Delta$ or less which we will call parts. The parts are pairwise disjoint. A part of size $n$ or more is said complete. Each $G_i$ will contain at least one complete part. If two $G_i$ overlap, they overlap on at least one complete part.
We build the parts sequentially. Suppose we are building the $i$-th part. Let $P$ be the union of all the parts created before this step.
Let $v\in V(G)-P$ be a vertex not yet included in a part. We create the biggest possible part $p_i$ by taking a connected induced graph of $G-P$ containing $v$. We repeat until the parts partition $V(G)$.
For each part $p_i$, we create $G_i$ by taking $p_i$, all the edges that overlap $p_i$, and all the complete parts that overlap some of these edges. Note that all edges are now covered.
We verify that we satisfy the requirements:
We set:

$N=(n+\Delta)+(n+\Delta)\Delta(\Delta-1)(n+\Delta)$
$G_i$ contains the part $p_i$ (size bounded by $n+\Delta$), and for each vertex $v$ of $p_i$ ($n+\Delta$ possible), for each edge $e$ containing $v$ ($\Delta$ possible), we add $e$, and for each $v'\in e, v'\neq v$ ($\Delta-1$ possible) $G_i$ can contain the complete part containing $v'$ (bounded by $n+\Delta$)

$m=1+(n+\Delta)(\Delta-1)(\Delta-1)$
If an edge $e$ is totally included in a part, it must be in $p_i$ for some $G_i$. The edge $e$ belongs to $G_i$, and if $p_i$ is complete, for each vertex $v$ of $p_i$ ($n+\Delta$), for each edge $e'$ that contains $v$ (but not contained in the part) ($\Delta-1$), for each vertex of $v'\in e', v'\neq v$ ($\Delta-1$), if $p_j$ is the part containing $v'$, $G_j$ contains $e$. If the edge is not included in a part, it belongs to at most $\Delta$ subgraphs (once for each vertex of the edge).


Every edge $e$ overlapping at least two parts must overlap at least one complete part because we could otherwise add $e$ to one of these parts to get a bigger part. For every non-complete part, a partially overlapping edge must exist (the graph is connected and of size at least $n$), so every $G_i$ will contain at least one complete part, and $|G_i|>n$.
If two subgraph overlap on a complete part, they both contain this complete part. Otherwise, they must overlap on a vertex covered by an edge $e$ that overlap multiple parts. Then they both contain at least one complete part spanned by $e$, thus their intersection is of size at least $n$.

Thanks for answering! I have a couple of questions: 1. when you say "it must contain at least one vertex covered", did you mean to say "uncovered"? 2. when you search for $P$, does it have to be outside $V(\widetilde G)$? If yes, then $P$ may not even exist. I think you didn't mean so because you say $P$ should contain vertices of $e\setminus V(\widetilde G)$, which doesn't exclude the possibility that $P$ contains some vertices in $V(\widetilde G)$ that are not in $e$. Just wanted to confirm with you before proceeding further.


I don’t see why $P$ must be a complete part. It could be that the vertices in $e\setminus V(\widetilde G)$ are not in any other edge. Then $P$ would be simply one of those vertices. Clearly that can’t be a complete part.



I meant uncovered, sorry about that.  2. It has to be outside of $V(\widetilde G)$. Indeed, if some vertex of $e\setminus V(\widetilde G)$ is not contained in a hyperedge with no uncovered vertex, $P$ may be empty or even undefined, but this is not really a problem, the important if that if possible, we extend it to a complete part. I will try to clarify that in the answer. 3. $P$ must not necessarily  be a complete part, only the part containing $v$. I will edit to clarify the intent.


I edited, and I now build the new $G_i$ out of an uncovered vertex instead of an edge, which simplifies a bit and fixes some problems.

Thanks for the update! I’m with you until you say “$P’$ is necessarily complete”. Are you saying it’s complete for every such $v’$, or for some $v’$? In either case, I don’t see why it has to be complete. Can you please explain more?

Also, when you add an $e$ that overlaps both $P$ and $\widetilde G$, there could be vertices in $e$ that don’t belong to either $P$ or $\widetilde G$. Which part(s) do those vertices belong to?

It is complete for some $v'$. I clarified in the answer.

Okay. Now there are vertices that don’t belong to any parts. So if $v’$ is such a vertex, there is no $P’$ associated with it, right? How to ensure that each $G_i$ has a complete part then?

I think there is still a problem, $v'$ may be one of those vertices that don't belong to any part, but I think that should be easily fixable. I will think about it a bit later.

I began to read the answer, but I do not understand what conditions the parts have to satisfy and why the required family of parts exists. I even do not see why the case when each part is a single vertex is forbidden.

@AlexRavsky currently, the proof is flawed, I think I found a fix yesterday evening, but I can't write it right now, I will do it hopefully soon. There is nothing that forbids part of size 1, we don't necessarily need the parts to partition the graph, just to be disjoint. Their sole purpose is to ensure a sufficient overlap between subgraphs.

@caduk. Great to hear that you found a fix! I’m waiting to see how it works out.

OK. But we need big parts, because each $G_i$ will contain a part of size at least $n$.

@Pranay I fixed my proof, hopefully, it is correct now. I changed some definitions and assumptions, but the construction is still rather straightforward.

@caduk The new proof looks awesome! I went through it again and didn't find any immediate flaws. I will go through it again tomorrow more carefully. (I have a specific class of hypergraphs in mind which helped me find the flaws in the previous proofs. I want to see how this proof works for that class explicitly.)

@caduk. I finally got the chance to go through it carefully. I am confused by the last assertion: if $G_i$ and $G_j$ contain $v$, then they must contain $p_e$ for some $e$ containing $v$. I am not sure this is true, can you explain?

Here's a picture of an example where the intersection is small: https://i.sstatic.net/zOTBbhB5.jpg. In this example, $G_2 \cap G_5$ contains exactly one vertex. I constructed the $G_i$'s using your algorithm.

@caduk. Could you please let me know if you have any updates on this answer?

@Pranay I hope that this time, it is correct, the construction is even simpler than before.

@caduk. Thanks for the update! Unfortunately, there’s still a problem: “Otherwise, they must overlap on a vertex covered by an edge $e$ that overlap multiple parts.” I don’t think this is true.

I mean, if they overlap on a vertex, they don’t have to overlap on the same edge containing that vertex.

@Pranay Yeah, if we have vertices $a,b,c,d,e$ in separate parts, with $d$ and $e$ in complete parts, if we have hyperedges ${a, b, d}$ and ${b,c,e}$, we have a problem. Unfortunately, I have no other ideas for the moment, I will keep thinking about it, but this problem is annoyingly hard to get it right, even though it look very simple to solve.

@caduk. I agree that’s it’s very annoying. I know how it works for any graph, and I also know how it works for a “hyper graph tree” (by which I mean the corresponding (bipartite) incidence graph on $V\times F$ is a tree). So I think it should work in general, but can’t seem to avoid small intersections.

^ I meant $V\times E$
